# ST-Link V2 not connecting to STM32F411

Tags: stm32, st-link

I got myself an STM32F411RCT6 and my ST-Link V2 is not detecting it using SWD, but I am able to program other STM32s using an even simpler setup, so I think there is something specific about this MCU that I'm missing. I've combed through the datasheet and looked at other schematics for the same chip, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or missing.

This is my schematic:
[image: STM32F411 Schematic]

**Some notes:**

- The ST-Link V2 supplies the power to the circuit (3.3v) and has only 4 wires connected (3.3v, GND, SWDIO, and SWCLK) I have no hardware reset on the programmer (My other STM32s use software resetting) but I did add a reset switch to the circuit to manually reset the chip.
- With the analog supply (VDDA) connected to 3.3v, the VCAP1 pin generates +- 1.2v (As it should, according to the datasheet). I initially did not connect VDDA to 3.3v, and the VCAP1 voltage was at 0v, but when bridging certain pins on the left side of the QFP64 chip with my finger, the VCAP1 voltage jumped to +- 0.7v, and the ST-Link V2 was able to detect the chip (I discovered this accidentally, and can reproduce it ‍♂️). It is not a reliable trick to try programming the chip with, but it makes me think that my problem lies with one or more of the pins on the left side of the package.
- The circuit on the schematic was the end result of my troubleshooting, I initially connected only one VDD and VSS pin, as well as the SWDIO and SWCLK pins to try and program it, and that is how I discovered the weird finger trick above - I can program my other STM32s (MM32F031C6T6) by only connecting the 4 pins from the ST-Link V2 (No capacitors, no oscillator, and no connections or switches on the BOOT and reset pins)
- I reset the chip with the BOOT0 pin pulled high to see if maybe I need to use the bootloader, but it did nothing.
- The HSE is not in use (I think) because it has not been programmed to
  use it yet, but I added it to my circuit as the intended oscillator. (The HSE also wasn't connected when the weird finger magic from the previous point happened)
- I have a 100nf capacitor connected between each of the VDD pins and GND, but I simplified my schematic.
- When connecting VDDA to 3.3v, I cannot reproduce the finger trick above, even though the VCAP1 voltage does jump around a bit when doing it.

**Update:**
I soldered a USB connection on to the circuit and changed the oscillator to a 25mhz one, and also removed the series resistor, to see if I can boot the chip into DFU mode, and this works, but only for a few seconds (Windows device manager shows the STM32 Bootloader USB device, and after a few seconds it disappears). After it disconnects from USB, it cannot be rebooted back into DFU mode again, unless I've left it powered off for a minute or so.

I also tried what was suggested in the comments with the capacitor on the reset switch, but as expected, this made no difference.

I tried connecting to it using STM32CubeProgrammer, and the USB connection also disappears the moment I connect to it.
I then found the with STM32CubeProgrammer I can connect to it using SWD, but I cannot write to, or erase the chip, it throws errors, but this connection remains conencted as long as I don't try writing to the chip.

I've looked at the ADAFruit STM32F411 Blackpill board to follow their circuit as closely as possible, but I'm not having any luck getting it to work reliably.

Below is the updated schematic.

[image: Updated STM32F411 Schematic]

Hopefully someone can help point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: There is no info how you connect to the ST-Link. Show that diagram, with VCC, GND, SWDAT and SWCLK, Reset too. How do you power the MCU, from where does the 3.3V come from?

Comment: @Justme I added the first point to my list to explain your comment

Comment: Is it a genuine ST-Link/V2 or a clone?

Comment: @Justme it is a clone, but I'm quite certain the programmer is not the problem, as can be deduced with the finger trick. It is a state of the chip that dictates if the programmer can communicate with it or not.

Comment: OK. Because that is important info you must add to question. A genuine ST-Link/V2 would not power a target, so I already thought I had solved your problem. The reset has a pull-up and no capacitor - that's not how it should be done.

Comment: If the target had no power, then the internal voltage regulator would not have generated 1.2v on the VCAP1 pin, so that point in the list should have proven an adequate power supply without additional explanations. As for resetting, this configuration can be seen on many other working schematics on the net, and it also works fine with my other STM32s, as well as with AVR MCUs, so I'm also certain that is not the problem

Comment: No the AVR is different. For STM32s you need to read how STM32 needs it. Don't compare with AVR, they are not related, they are different. There's no bypass caps either. Have all power and ground pins been soldered properly, no accidental bad connections or broken PCB traces?

Comment: As per the 2nd last point in my list, there are decoupling capacitors between every VDD pin and GND, I just simplified the schematic. All connections were tested with a multimeter and it all works 100% so that also isn't the problem. Also, for testing purposes, you don't need decoupling capacitors, they are intended for transient stability

Comment: That is the problem of simplifying the schematic. We can't guess what you really have or don't have. And bypass caps are important. MCUs do consume current at the clock rate, so there's the transients already. Even more important at higher speeds and more sophisticated MCUs. I suggest fix the reset with capacitor. Or try another MCU, this may be now damaged due to not all supplies being connected in the beginning.

Comment: The reset switch was an optional test I did, normally you would make use of software resetting and don't even need a hardware reset for programming. And the lack of a capacitor on the reset switch wouldn't damage the chip, nor would the lack of decoupling caps, it'll just cause instability or reset incosistencies in the case of the reset switch

Comment: The capacitor on reset is mandatory for power-up reset. It is not optional. Please read datasheet, hardware getting started guide, and reference schematics which describe minimum requirements for a properly working system.

Comment: The capacitors for the LDO are not what the datasheet recommends. Did you measure the 3.3V line with a scope to make sure it's stable?

Comment: Also the LDO has a minimum load current.

Comment: The 100uF electrolytic capacitor on regulator output may be part of the problem. It may only make things worse than help. USB specs have a hard energy inrush limit that must be followed, and directly on VBUS a 10uF capacitance is maximum allowed. The 25 MHz crystal is also absurdly high and may cause problems with DFU, something like 8 MHz would be more reasonable.

Comment: @nanash1 Not with a scope no, Only a multimeter. I actually want to use this chip to build a simple scope

Comment: @Justme I don't have an 8mhz crystal, only a ceramic resonator, but AN2606 doc says 8Mhz, 14.7456Mhz, or 25Mhz should work. I'll try the ceramin resonator and see what it does, or will ceramic resonators not work? (The doc says external clock, not specifying crystal or ceramic resonator)

Comment: It doesn't say that. For F411, only integer multiple of 1 MHz is allowed, and ceramic resonators are not accurate enough to be suitable for USB.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the updated schematic, I believe your power supply is unstable. If we take a look at the datasheet of the [AP1117](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP1117.pdf) that you're using to generate the 3.3V, it says:

> **Input Capacitors**
>
> To ensure stable operation, the input supply must be low impedance up to a frequency of a few MHz. This requires a closely placed input
> decoupling capacitor of **4.7μF minimum**. This can be either ceramic or solid tantalum. The ESR of this capacitor must be less than 0.5Ω.

According to the schematic, yours is 100nF which is obviously not sufficient.

Furthermore, the minimum load current of the AP1117 is between 5 and 10 mA (page 4 of the datasheet). Since you have nothing connected to the LDO besides the MCU, we can look at it's [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f411ce.pdf) to see how much current it's expected to draw.

[image]

As we can see, even when in run mode with all peripherals enabled, it can fall well below 10 mA and even 5 mA. In sleep mode and stop mode its current consumption is even lower (as expected).

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of the minimum current limit. I'll swap out the capacitor and just add an LED to the circuit to bump the load up, and try again. Hopefully that solves the DFU issue. Thanks for the feedback